# Finite-difference method: Hints on how to solve this system of 1D differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I am trying to solve the following differential equation describing the steady-state carrier density and photon density in a laser diode:
$$AN(z)+BN(z)^2+CN(z)^3=\frac{\eta_iI}{qV}-v_gg(N)(S^+(z)+S^-(z))$$
$$\frac{dS^+(z)}{dz}=(\Gamma g(N)-\alpha_i)S^+(z)+\frac{\Gamma R_{sp}'}{v_g}$$
$$-\frac{dS^-(z)}{dz}=(\Gamma g(N)-\alpha_i)S^-(z)+\frac{\Gamma R_{sp}'}{v_g}$$
The reflections at the facets of the laser define the following boundary conditions:
$$S^+(0)=R_1S^-(0)$$
$$S^-(L)=R_2S^+(L)$$
I am trying to use the finite-difference method, where I divide the laser into $M+1$ points, so I make the following approximation:
$$\frac{dS}{dz}\approx\frac{S(z+\Delta z)-S(z-\Delta z)}{2\Delta z}\equiv\frac{S_{i+1}-S_{i-1}}{2\Delta z}$$
This gives me a system of $3(M+1)$ equations:
$$AN_i+BN_i^2+CN_i^3=\frac{\eta_iI}{qV}-v_gg(N_i)(S_i^++S_i^-),\quad(i=1,...,M+1)$$
$$\frac{S_{i+1}^+-S_{i-1}^+}{2\Delta z}=(\Gamma g(N_i)-\alpha_i)S_i^++\frac{\Gamma R_{sp}'}{v_g},\quad(i=2,...,M)$$
$$-\frac{S_{i+1}^--S_{i-1}^-}{2\Delta z}=(\Gamma g(N_i)-\alpha_i)S_i^-+\frac{\Gamma R_{sp}'}{v_g},\quad(i=2,...,M)$$
$$S^+_{1}=R_1S^-_{1}$$
$$S^-_{M+1}=R_2S^+_{M+1}$$
This is where I run into a problem. I have two more equations I need to define:
$$\frac{S_{M+2}^+-S_{M}^+}{2\Delta z}=(\Gamma g(N_{M+1})-\alpha_i)S_{M+1}^++\frac{\Gamma R_{sp}'}{v_g}$$
$$\frac{S_{2}^--S_{-1}^-}{2\Delta z}=(\Gamma g(N_{1})-\alpha_i)S_{1}^-+\frac{\Gamma R_{sp}'}{v_g}$$
However, this leads to two variables that are "ill-defined", namely $S_{-1}^-$ and $S_{M+2}^+$.

I tried to solve this problem by using forward and backward differences at the edges, instead of central differences, to get rid of these out-of-the-boundary variables. However, this reduces the accuracy of the solution significantly. In fact, for $M=100$, I will then get the following result for $N$, $S^+$, $S^-$:

[image: Carrier density N][image: Photon densities S]

I got this result by using Matlab's symbolic numerical solver *vpasolve*. Changing the initial values did not change the result, so I suspect that the result is stable. It also satisfies the boundary conditions nicely. However, the values of $N$ at the edges are not physical, and especially $N$ (in the middle) and $S^+$ have pronounced oscillation, which should not exist in the real laser. I suspect this is due to the fact that I use the less-accurate forward and backward differences at the edges, which deteriorates the accuracy of the whole system. I could of course increase the number of points, but the calculation is heavy as it is.

I would like to use central differences at the edges as well, but I am not sure how it works, because of the two additional variables $S_{-1}^-$ and $S_{M+2}^+$, as I am not sure how to handle them. This would also mean that I would have $3(M+1)+2$ variables, but only $3(M+1)$ equations, so would I not then get multiple possible solutions?

Any hints are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but I'm pretty sure you're misdiagnosing where the oscillations come from. It looks like the oscillations have period 2. My guess is that the use of the central differences everywhere in the interior causes the function restricted to even i and the function restricted to odd i to be different, in the sense that there's no reason to have S(i) be particularly close to S(i+1), other than due to some condition you propagate all the way from the edge. In contrast, S(i) must be close to S(i+2) because you are explicitly defining their difference to be small.

Comment: @SamZbarsky You bring a very valid point. So, would you then say that using forward and backward propagations might actually produce a more stable result?

Comment: @SamZbarsky I changed the code, and used forward propagation for the forward propagating wave S+, and backward propagation for the backward propagating wave S-. I was able to get rid off the oscillations. Thank you for the suggestion! However, I am still getting a weird unphysical jump at the right edge of the graph for S+ and N, and I am not quite sure of what the origin is. It is strange that the left edge does not show such a jump.

Comment: @SamZbarsky Never mind, this was just a problem with my code! Now it works beautifully. Thank you so much for your help!